# React: Local storage getItem() was not work after the page reload

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native

Step 1: After the system login api response token was added local storage using setItem().

`window.localStorage.setItem("user", result.token);`

Step 2: After the token added local storage getItem() working fine.

`localStorage.getItem("user")`

Step 3: Then we used page reload

`window.location = window.location.origin;`

Step 5: Now the situation local storage getItem() is not working. It's show as "NULL" value.

`localStorage.getItem("user")`

We used Laravel backend for Api service.
Do you have any idea please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is separated by protocol://host:port, so if you are redirecting to a page that has a different domain/subdomain you will not have access to the local storage that you populated.

Also check when you upload the site on the server if you need to generate key for JWT key on time of installation of JWT Modules.

Comment: Step 3: we just reload same app using `window.location = window.location.origin;`

Answer (score 0):

I think local storage getItem() shows `null` because after step3. Your app will restart. `setItem` will call again, and maybe `result.token` is `null` so user in local storage will change to null.

Comment: Step 3 : we just reload the page. when the page reload, if the token available URL redirect to the user page.